# Two interface 's instance can reference each other?

Tags: c#, interface, circular-reference

Using C#

```
Interface A,
Interface B,

Class AA:A
{

 public AA(A a)
{
 //...
}

}

Class BB:B
{

public BB(B b)
{
  //...
}

}
```

are the code works fine and not cause the circular reference problem?

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with interfaces. AA could take an AA. That would be a linked list with the last element necessarily being null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not?  Syntax aside, self-similar structures appear all over computer science.  Consider a binary tree: each node has a reference to two other trees (represented by their root nodes.)  A typical way to make such a tree is a type that is constructed with not one, but two references to other instances of the type.

More generally, cycles in the *type system* are not the same as cycles in the *object graph*.  Usually the first is by design, but the second has a way of turning into bugs..

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why object graph cycles could in general turn into bugs? Sure, cycles do cause issues in specific cases like serialization but in general they occur often, sometimes even as parts of design patterns (to name MVP/MVVM).

Comment: Only because (in my experience) they are unexpected.  Naively traversing such a cycle with (say) a recursive function would lead to infinite descent.

Comment: However if you yourself are writing code that could encounter a cycle in the object graph here are [cycle detection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) out there.